# Is it possible to put url link preview inside textview in android?

Tags: android

I am making a bulletin board app. I wish that [Text] and [Preview video] coexist in a post that a user copied and pasted a YouTube video link.

[image]

I tried several ways with `TextView` and `com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:11.0.1`, but I couldn't get the video preview to exist between the text as in the picture. how can i make it like that?? And other than TextView, is there a way to show a preview at the bottom when there are fewer links in EditText?

Answer (score 0):

**code is just for the link and it is clickable to jump to the link**

```
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="https://twitter.com/NiajNm"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        />
```

**If you want to play video in activity via the link you will need API and need to implement VideoView and MediaController **

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We know how hyperlinks are handled when links in url format are entered in TextView. What I want is to be able to embed something like a ```VideoView``` into a ```TextView```. We don't know how many ```VideoViews``` we need because we don't know how many links the user will enter. Can I put a ```Video``` in a ```TextView```? If yes, what should I do, and if not, what should I do?

Comment: I think for this you can use expandable Textview with recycler. otherwise  its not a good idea to put a video view in textview where you have option to make item layout.